# How can I split text into a list everytime it finds a character in JS?

Tags: javascript, loops, save

I am trying to create a code to iterate through a save code, and I think it’ll be something like this :

`Username;Password;Points`

How can I split the above text into a list like this : `[Username, Password, Points]` ,everytime it finds a semicolon using Javascript?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try the string method [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)? Maybe `str.split(';')`? If you did a search for "split text javascript" you would have come across all the documentation you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `split`:

```js
var input = "Username;Password;Points";
var parts = input.split(";");
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: How can I add the substrings into a list?
(Like this : `[Username,Password,Points]`)

Comment: @KornRT2018 The output of `split` is an _array_, not a list.  But a list probably will suffice for what you need here.